# sql query with multiple headers and multiple counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-query-store

I have a table with client task details (attached picture). I want result like number of tasks received for a particular month for each client, no. of tasks completed within 5days from the start date and its compliance. could someone help with a SQL query

[image]

```
client | No.of tasks of a month | No.of tasks completed on time | % of compliance
A      | 5                      | 4                             | 75%
```

Comment: Please share the table structure you have created.

Comment: Off topic but 4 out of 5 is 80% not 75%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your last comment, this is a minimal, not-production-ready, idea:

suppose you have a combobox for months and year

```
cbYear.DataSource = new int[] { 2017, 2018, 2019 };
cbMonth.DataSource = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
```

and a datagridview *dgv*, you can do something like this (in a button)

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"
select 
    x.Client
,   x.MonthTasks
,   x.CompletedOnTime
,   Compliance = x.CompletedOnTime * 100 / x.MonthTasks
from (
    select 
        t.Client
   ,    MonthTasks = Count(1)
   ,    CompletedOnTime = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.TaskStart, t.TaskEnd)<=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   from tasks as t
   where
        year(t.TaskStart) = @year
   and month(t.TaskStart) = @month
   group by t.Client
) as x
order by x.Client
        ";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", cbYear.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", cbMonth.SelectedIndex +1);

        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
        dgv.Refresh();
```

I repeat you have to catch any errors, maybe transform the query in a stored procedure, but this can be a starting point.

Comment: Oh clearly you need to update the connection string to your case

Comment: I understand you want to help the OP but answering another question written in a comment like this is not a good idea. It is better to ask the OP to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a quite recent sql-server, try something like this (change the name of table and columns as appropriate).

```
select 
    x.Client
,   x.MonthTasks
,   x.CompletedOnTime
,   Compliance = x.CompletedOnTime * 100 / x.MonthTasks
from (
    select 
        t.Client
    ,   MonthTasks = Count(1)
    ,   CompletedOnTime = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.TaskStart, t.TaskEnd)<=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    from tasks as t
    where
        year(t.TaskStart) = 2018    -- put year
    and month(t.TaskStart) = 10     -- put month
    group by t.Client
) as x
order by x.Client
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mirko. I use 2008 R2

Comment: Mirko, can you also please help me to know how to run this query from C# and year and month will be a input from dropdownlist. I want to present the out of the query in a gridview